# Displaying next view after splashscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to load a view of my choice after the default splash view of iphone launches. Does someone know how to achieve this ? i am new to xcode and ios development.

Comment: Check http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: There is a project at Github called [LaunchImageTransition](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/LaunchImageTransition), it should provide a custom view after the `Default.png` image has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[self setUpSplash];` method in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method. And add following **Three** method in **AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void) setUpSplash {
    self.splashImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    [self.splashImgView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview: self.splashImgView];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(closeSplashWithTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)closeSplashWithTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ToggleViews" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    // Make the animatable changes.
    splashImgView.alpha = 0.0;
    self.mvNavigationController.view.alpha = 1.0;

    // Commit the changes and perform the animation.
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(closeSplashWithTimerAgain:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)closeSplashWithTimerAgain:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    [self.splashImgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```