# iPhone splash screens for web applications

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, iphone, iphone-web-app

I know iphone(web app) doesnt support landscape mode for splash screen in web app.But ı have to force splash screen to landscape mode because when app is opened landscape mode splash screen is shown badly.how can ı do it?

Comment: use a rotated image for splash.

Comment: Check  my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212431/displaying-next-view-after-splashscreen/14212743#14212743) may be helpful in your case :)

Comment: sorry this problem is for web app not native iphone app.

Comment: but try it... 90% may be solve your problem

Comment: You cannot force a web app to open in Landscape mode on an iOS device. You may however design your splash image in "landscape form" meaning that your verbiage and everything is turned if the user holds the phone upright - so hopefully they would turn their screen accordingly by the time the web app loads.